# How to find posts I had flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging, flags

In previous design of Ask Ubuntu, there was an option to find the posts/comments I had flagged. I cannot find it in the recent design.

How to find the posts I had flagged?

Comment: It's been quite some time since the new design is in place right?

Comment: @RandomPerson Yes. I thought about asking this question, but never did.

Comment: I'm curious to know... so you couldn't see your flag history since past few weeks till BeastOfCaerbannog gave an answer? Or is this more of an awareness post for fellow users?

Comment: @RandomPerson No, I could not see my flag history for the past couple of months.

Comment: Oops! That would have been annoying! Having an eye on MSE would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the *Activity* tab of your profile, click on the *helpful flags* item in the *IMPACT* box.

> [image: helpful flags item]

Despite the name, this is the place where you can find all your flags, both *helpful* and *declined*.

Comment: 'Mouseover' gives a few extra hints as well...